# How to download multiple files wiht the same name with wget in python

Tags: python, wget

I am trying to download multiple files using `wget` but because they have the same name, each time a file is downloaded it replaces the previously downloaded file.

my current code is:

```
import wget
for link in links:
    wget.download(link ,r'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx')
```

Is there a way you can get it to automatically change the name so the next file can be downloaded? It doesn't matter what name. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this, it basically adds a number at the end of each file and thus makes their names different.

```py
for c, link in enumerate(links):
    wget.download(link ,r'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx' + str(c))
```

Comment: thanks @malisit. It seems to work once i add in `+ str(c)` instead however it is saving the files into the main directory and not the `'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx'` folder?

Comment: Is the last xxx on your path also a directory?

Comment: Yes it is the folder name that i wanted it to be saved into